# Animation Problem Box is bouncing

Tags: animation, mesh, rigid-body-simulation, collision

Hi my problem is when I start the animation the box keeps bouncing or slides trough the mesh

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNvA8.jpg

[image]

Comment: Hello, it works fine for me (Blender 3.3.0), maybe apply the scale of your objects?

Comment: thank you for the help.Seems like the problem disappeared over night.But now the the box doesnt move as fast as the conveyor belt any suggestions how I can change that ?

Comment: maybe cheat with an invisible mesh that follows the belt and push the cube?